# Regex to match text from multiple links

Tags: regex

How to extract links which contain a certain word?

For e.g.:

`https://www.test.com/text/1@@@https://www.test.com/text/word/2@@@https://www.test.com/text/text/word/3@@@https://www.test.com/3/text@@@https://www.test.com/word/3/text/text`

How to search "**word**" from below regex?

`((https:).*?(@@@))`

The result should be like this

https://www.test.com/text/**word**/2

https://www.test.com/text/text/**word**/3

https://www.test.com/**word**/3/text/text

Comment: You can probably split on `@@@` and match array item with `/word/`

Comment: `s.split('@@@').filter(x => x.indexOf('/word/') > 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to build such regex. First we need to find the beginning of url:

```
/(https?:\/\//
```

We add `?` after `https` for `http` urls.

Then we need to find any text except `@@@`, so we need to add:

```
(?:(?!@@@).)*
```

which means - any amount of characters not starting a `@@@` sequence.

Also we need to add word itself and previous sub-expression again, since word can be surrounded by any text:

```
word(?:(?!@@@).)*
```

But the thing is that last sub-expression will skip last character before `@@@`, so we need to add one more thing to handle it:

```
.(?=@@@|$)
```

which means - any character followed by `@@@` or end of string. The final expression will look like:

```
/(https:\/\/(?:(?!@@@).)*word(?:(?!@@@).)*.(?=@@@|$))/g
```

But i believe, it's better to just split text by `@@@` and then check for needed word by `String.prototype.includes`.

Comment: Hi @Andres, Your answer is really helpful, Can we capture first match, second match etc.? '(https:\/\/(.(?!@@@))*word(.(?!@@@))*.(?=(@@@)|$)){first/second/third}'

Comment: I fixed the common issue in the use of a tempered greedy token, but the `/(https:\/\/(?:(?!@@@).)*word(?:(?!@@@).)*.(?=@@@|$))/g` looks suspicious due to a `.`  before `(?=@@@|$)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can we capture the second/third/fourth match by passing the parameter to regex?

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed No, not to regex, but you can easily do this with Oracle SQL `regexp_substr` and similar functions in other regex powered . You just do that with code.

Answer (score 1):

### Previous answer

You for sure looking for this regular expression:

```
https://www.test.com/(text/)*word/\d+(/text)*
```

Here is how you can use it in *JavaScript* context (very slash `/` is escaped by backslash `\/`):

```js
var str = 'https://www.test.com/text/1@@@https://www.test.com/text/word/2@@@https://www.test.com/text/text/word/3@@@https://www.test.com/3/text@@@https://www.test.com/word/3/text/text'; 
var urls = str.match(/https:\/\/www.test.com\/(text\/)*word\/\d+(\/text)*/g);
console.log(urls);
```

In the array you get exactly the elements you wanted.

### Update the answer after update question and adding comment by the author

If you need take the `word`s from your example string, then you have to use a little more complex regular exception:

```js
var str = 'https://www.test.com/text/1@@@https://www.test.com/text/word/2@@@https://www.test.com/text/text/word/3@@@https://www.test.com/3/text@@@https://www.test.com/word/3/text/text'; 
var urls = str.match(/(?<=\/)\w+(?=\/\d+\/\w)|(?<=(\w\/\w+\/))\w+(?=\/\d)/g);
console.log(urls);
```

#### Explanation

Here is regular expression `/(?<=(\w\/\w+\/))\w+(?=\/\d)|(?<=\/)\w+(?=\/\d+\/\w)/g`, limited by `/.../` and with the `g` flag forcing pattern searches for occurrence.

The regular expression has two alternatives `...|...`

The first one `(?<=\/)\w+(?=\/\d+\/\w)` captures cases when the searched word is directly behind the slash `(?<=\/)` and before more words behind the number `(?=\/\d+\/\w)`.

> https://www.test.com/word/3/text/text

The second alternative `(?<=(\w\/\w+\/))\w+(?=\/\d)` captures cases where the word is preceded by other words following the domain `(?<=(\w\/\w+\/))` (in fact two slashes separated by alphanumeric characters) and the searched word is immediately before the slash followed by the number `(?=\/\d)`.

> https://www.test.com/text/word/2
>
> https://www.test.com/text/text/word/3

All slashes must be escaped: `\/`.

The construction `(?<=...)` means *lookbehind* in regular expressions and `(?=...)` means *lookahead* in regular expressions.

**Note 1.** The above example currently only works well in a Chrome browser, as [that](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> (...) now lookbehind is part of the ECMAScript 2018 specification. As of this writing (late 2018), Google's Chrome browser is the only popular JavaScript implementation that supports lookbehind. So if cross-browser compatibility matters, you can't use lookbehind in JavaScript.

**Note 2.** [Lookbehnd](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), even if it is interpreted correctly, in most regular expression engines must contain a *fixed length* regular expression, which I do not keep in the example above, because this one is still valid and works for regular expression engines used in Google Chrome's [JavaScript engine](https://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html), [JGsoft engine](https://www.regular-expressions.info/jgsoft.html) and [.NET framework RegEx classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).

**Note 3.** The [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) syntax or its poorer [`\K`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) replacement are widely supported by many regular expression engines used in a large group of programming languages.

More explanation about regular expressions which I used you can find for example [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed if you need any more specific hints, explanations or description, please let me know

Comment: I want to apply a generic approach to search a word from an individual link using regex only. Not specific to the example which contains text/digit/domain.

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed your question suggested something else... It's a pity.

Comment: But thank you for your comment @MusakkhirSayyed. I'll update my answer to that what you exactly needed. BDW: If I understed you well then the accepted answer is not what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the `word` has to be a part of the pathname, you might use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in combination with [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and check if the parts of the pathname contain word.

```js
let str = 'https://www.test.com/text/1@@@https://www.test.com/text/word/2@@@https://www.test.com/text/text/word/3@@@https://www.test.com/3/text@@@https://www.test.com/word/3/text/text';
let filteredUrls = str.split("@@@")
  .filter(s =>
    new URL(s).pathname
    .split('/')
    .includes('word')
  );
console.log(filteredUrls);
```

If you want to use regex only and [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) are supported (The javascript tag has been removed) you might use:

```
https?://[^@w]*(?:@(?!@@)|w(?!ord)|[^@w]*)++word.*?(?=@@@|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XGztOv/1)

Comment: Can we slove it by regex only?

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed I have updated the answer and added a possible regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may first split by `@@@` then check whether `/word/` exists in each element:

```js
var s = 'https://www.test.com/text/1@@@https://www.test.com/text/word/2@@@https://www.test.com/text/text/word/3@@@https://www.test.com/3/text@@@https://www.test.com/word/3/text/text';

var result = [];

s.split(/@@@/).forEach(function(el) {
   if (el.includes('/word/'))
    result.push(el);
})

// or else by using filter
// result = s.split(/@@@/).filter(el => el.includes('/word/'))

console.log(result);
```